# Google Spreadsheet: ImportXML and Divided by Zero Error

Tags: import, google-sheets, divide-by-zero

On Google Spreadsheet, I have several calculations based on data parsed by the importXML function.
If the import function doesn't find any data, then many of my calculations are not working because of DIV/0 errors. Which is normal and fine.

But, when the import function find data and update the data sheet, it seems that some division are not "updated" and stay stuck on the DIV/0 error, even though the denominator is no longer zero.
In fact, I have even cases where the cell with a division is well updated but a dependant cell, without any division, shows a DIV/0 error.

After a couple of long seconds, it usually correct itself.

I would like to avoid these errors or force Spreadsheet to immediatly recalculate, eventually by a function.

Thanks for reading,

Bkyn

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your expression in the iferror() function to avoid having to deal with errors in the first place:

=iferror(value, value if error)

a1: 2
b2: 1
c3: =iferror(A1/B2, "error")
result: 2

a1: 2
b2: 0
c3: =iferror(A1/B2, "error")
result: error

Or whatever 'value if error' result would be most useful to be a placeholder for when things are evaluated to DIV/0.

Comment: That's unfortunately not solving the problem.
The dependent cells will continue to see the "error" text and will therefore give an error.
It really seems that the problem is somewhere in the way Google refresh the formulas...

Comment: Google Apps do refresh in funky, unpredictable ways, sorry this didn't solve it, it won't help to use a number like -1 in place of the string "error"? or some other number that gives an innocuous result that isn't an error?

Comment: Then, "-1" or any other figure is used in the dependent calculation.